# Дан следующий массив: let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']; Создайте из этого массива следующий объект:

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста что не так?

Дан следующий массив: `let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];` Создайте из этого массива следующий объект: `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5};`

```js
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
let obj = {};
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  obj[i] = arr[i];
  obj[obj[i]] = i + 1;

}
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Присвоение `obj[i] = arr[i];` - лишнее

Comment: Тогда такой вывод :// [object Object] 
{
  "undefined": 5
}

Comment: Так и вот это `obj[obj[i]] = i + 1;` нужно заменять на `obj[arr[i]] = i + 1;`

Comment: Благодарю  Вас

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавление в `arr` элемента-строки по ключу `i` - лишнее.

Надо сделать так:

```js
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
let obj = {};

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  // Тут не надо добавлять obj[i] = arr[i], потому что это лишнее.
  obj[arr[i]] = i + 1;
}

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Тогда вывод : // [object Object] 
{
  "undefined": 5
}

Comment: Извините, не заметил ошибку в вашем коде

Comment: @KaterynaBlbn Теперь нормально должно быть, скопируйте новый код

Comment: Благодарю  Вас

Comment: @KaterynaBlbn да не за что, ещё галочку поставьте)

Comment: что бы вопрос был решённым